# How to populate a textbox from the result of a query

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a combobox and a Textbox on my form.

If a user chooses a value from the Combobox for example: **Cvalue** then I want to populate the textbox with the results of a query, for example :

```
Select S1 From Test where Name=Cvalue
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection

    Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ssql = "select s1 from test where cvalue='" & Combo0.Value & "'"

    rs.Open ssql, con

    Do Until rs.EOF = True

       Text2.SetFocus

       Text2.Text = rs.Fields!s1

       rs.MoveNext

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

If the textbox you are populating is unbound (doesn't have to update a field in the underlying form data source) then you can use `DLOOKUP` in the text box's control source and avoid VBA:

```
=DLOOKUP("S1", "Test", "cvalue='" & forms!MyForm!Combo0 & "'")
```

Answer (score 1):

`txtBox1.text = myResults.GetString`

Provided txtBox1 is your textbox, and myResults are the recordset from your query. No loop required.